# CAGradientLayer different result between iPhone SE and others

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer

I have a CAGradientLayer, nothing complex

```
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, Colors.Corporate.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = bounds
    mainImage.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

I have a different result on iPhoneSE(Simulator) and iPod(Real Device)... any other device, iPhoneX(Real Device) and iPhone8(Simulator) work ad expected.

[image: iPhoneSE] [image: Iphone8]

The gradient overlay in the bottom part is different. Anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on when the layer is created and inserted in the sublayer hieararchy. Can you try to update its frame on `viewWillAppear` (if you have access to the layer from view controller) or similar?

A layer like that should always follow parent view's bounds when they change.